# Powershell and Excel sheet automation

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am trying to make an automated process with powershell to import the csv that I have, and to automate the report that I generate on a monthly basis. I am just starting and here is what I have.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("U:\Local Group Members.csv")
$excel.visible=$true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$sheet =$book.worksheets.items(1)
$sheet.name = 'Local Group Memb'
$sheet.Activate() | Out-Null
$sheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true
$wb.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```

I just tried this, and it gives me this error.[Error I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMXJZ.png)

How do I bold the first Row?

Comment: Either loop over the cells or use a Range instead of `Cells.Item`

Answer (score 1):

> $sheet =$book.worksheets.items(1)

Remove the s in items

Replace $book with $excel

$sheet =$excel.worksheets.item(1)

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Local Group Members.csv")
$excel.visible=$true
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$sheet =$excel.worksheets.item(1)
$sheet.name = 'Local Group Memb'
$sheet.Activate() | Out-Null
$sheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true
$wb.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track, you just need to add:

```
$wb.Save()
$excel.Quit()
```

I would also recommend just bolding the first Row, unless that is too much.

```
$sheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true
```